# Why does Google colab say: chmod: cannot access 'RDP.sh': No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, chmod, rdp

When I put the following code in the Google Colab Run cell:

```
! wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alok676875/RDP/main/RDP.sh &> /dev/null
! chmod +x RDP.sh
! ./RDP.sh
```

The result is as follows:

```
chmod: cannot access 'RDP.sh': No such file or directory
/bin/bash: ./RDP.sh: No such file or directory
```

Please tell, where is the error and what is the solution. Thank you

Comment: Is your `wget` link valid? As for me it tells `404: Not Found`, so it might be the problem - you cannot download the file.

Answer (score 1):

this file

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alok676875/RDP/main/RDP.sh

was deleted so you can't download it.